# How do I check if installed software on a computer is the licensed version or trial version?

Tags: windows-7, license

Is there any way to find all unlicensed software's in my windows 7 ?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no easy way for that.

OS doesn't know about software's licensing status, you need to open and check them one by one.